# Efficiently subtract row from array n times and create a new dimension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array of size A = (x,y). I want to subtract 100 different rows from each row in array A. So the end size is (x,y,100). How do I do this efficiently?

In pseudo code this would look something like:

```
for i in range(100):
  list.append([A - B[i]])
np.stack(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your loop, it looks like you expect a `(100, x, y)` (or `(100, 1, x, y)`?) shape as output.

You can use broadcasting for that:

```
out = (A-B[:,None,None])

# out.shape
(100, x, y)
```

For `(100, 1, x, y)`:

```
out = (A-B[:,None,None,None])

# out.shape
(100, 1, x, y)
```

And for `(x, y, 100)`:

```
out = A[...,None] - B[None,None]

# out.shape
(x, y, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

# Create an array A of size (x, y)
A = np.random.rand(x, y)

# Create an array B of size (100, y) containing the rows to subtract
B = np.random.rand(100, y)

# Subtract B from each row in A using broadcasting
result = A[:, np.newaxis, :] - B
```

The resulting array will have shape `(x, 100, y)`

And the above code, `A[:, np.newaxis, :]` reshapes the original array A to have shape (x, 1, y). This is done to align the dimensions for broadcasting with B. Then, broadcasting automatically extends B to match the shape of A and performs element-wise subtraction.

The resulting array result will have shape (x, 100, y), where each element at position (i, j, k) represents the subtraction of row j from row i in array A.

By using broadcasting instead of a loop, you can take advantage of numpy’s optimized operations and achieve better performance.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?